# I am New To Flutter And I am In Bind with SetState Operation, I am Trying to Organize Code in a Block By Block way but setState is not working,

Tags: flutter, dart

This is The code I am using, I have Created a New Folder name HomePage in the lib folder and placed my Home.dart file there, Every thing was great until I got to setState. setState is Simply not Working.

Main.Dart Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_project1/HomePage/Home.dart';

main() => runApp(new DarkX());

class DarkX extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new DarkXState();
  }

}

class DarkXState extends State<DarkX>{

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = new DarkXAppHomePage().createHomePage();
    return home;
  }

}
```

Home.Dart Code `

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DarkXAppHomePage {

    var _isLoading = true;

    createHomePage(){
        var homePageScaffold = createHomePageScaffold();
        return MaterialApp(home: homePageScaffold, debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
    }


    //Scaffold For Home Page
    createHomePageScaffold(){
      var homeAppbar = homeAppBar();
      var homebody = homeBody();
      var scaffold = new Scaffold(appBar: homeAppbar, body: homebody,);
      return scaffold;
    }

    //AppBar For Home Page
    homeAppBar(){
      var text = createText('Welcome');
      var refreshbutton = refreshButton(refreshHomePage);
      var appBar = new AppBar(title: text,actions: <Widget>[refreshbutton],);
      return appBar;
    }

    //Body For Home Page
    homeBody(){
      var loadingState = _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : createText('Finished Loading');
      return new Center(child: loadingState);
    }

    refreshButton(Function onPress){
      var refreshicon = refreshIcon();
      var refreshbutton = new IconButton(icon: refreshicon, onPressed: (){
        onPress();
      },);
      return refreshbutton;
    }

    //homepage Refresh Action
    refreshHomePage(){
      setState(){
        _isLoading = false;
      }
    }

    //Create Text
    createText( String text ){
      var newText = new Text(text);
      return newText;
    }

    //Refresh Icon
    refreshIcon(){
      var refreshicon = new Icon(Icons.refresh);
      return refreshicon;
    }

}
```

now when I use setState in refreshHomePage function, its not working and an warning "The declaration 'setState' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'setState'.dart(unused_element)" is showing. Any suggestions Please.
Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should remember that's `setState()` method is a method of an `State<E extends StatefulWidget>` class. According your source code, you are calling `setState()` method of `DarkXAppHomePage` class. The `DarkXAppHomePage` class are not   both of `State` class and `State`'s subclass. So that reason, your code did not work. Your `setState()` method did wrong implement also. Your solution for you, I advise you 2 steps.

The first step, you should read [this docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro) again carefully.

The second step, I will help you step by step modify your source.

**Step 1**: Your original source.

```
class DarkXAppHomePage {
  var _isLoading = true;

  createHomePage(){
    var homePageScaffold = createHomePageScaffold();
    return MaterialApp(home: homePageScaffold, debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
  }


  //Scaffold For Home Page
  createHomePageScaffold(){
    var homeAppbar = homeAppBar();
    var homebody = homeBody();
    var scaffold = new Scaffold(appBar: homeAppbar, body: homebody,);
    return scaffold;
  }

  //AppBar For Home Page
  homeAppBar(){
    var text = createText('Welcome');
    var refreshbutton = refreshButton(refreshHomePage);
    var appBar = new AppBar(title: text,actions: <Widget>[refreshbutton],);
    return appBar;
  }

  //Body For Home Page
  homeBody(){
    var loadingState = _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : createText('Finished Loading');
    return new Center(child: loadingState);
  }

  refreshButton(Function onPress){
    var refreshicon = refreshIcon();
    var refreshbutton = new IconButton(icon: refreshicon, onPressed: (){
      onPress();
    },);
    return refreshbutton;
  }

  //homepage Refresh Action
  refreshHomePage(){
    setState(){
      _isLoading = false;
    } // ★ => Look at this, wrong implement. You have to put a method as `setState()` parameter instead of write a new `setState()` method liked that.
  }

  //Create Text
  createText( String text ){
    var newText = new Text(text);
    return newText;
  }

  //Refresh Icon
  refreshIcon(){
    var refreshicon = new Icon(Icons.refresh);
    return refreshicon;
  }
```

}

**Step 2**: Shorten this for make it easy to read. (Maybe not easy to understand. However we will update it soon.).

```
class DarkXAppHomePage {  
  var _isLoading = true;

  createHomePage() => MaterialApp(home: createHomePageScaffold(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);

  //Scaffold For Home Page
  createHomePageScaffold() => Scaffold(appBar: homeAppBar(), body: homeBody());

  //AppBar For Home Page
  homeAppBar() => AppBar(title: createText('Welcome'), actions: <Widget>[refreshButton(refreshHomePage)]);

  //Body For Home Page
  homeBody() => Center(child: _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : createText('Finished Loading'));

  refreshButton(Function onPress) => IconButton(icon: refreshIcon(), onPressed: () => onPress());

  //homepage Refresh Action
  refreshHomePage() => setState(() => _isLoading = false); // ★ => `() => _isLoading = false` is the short way represent an anonymous method. You put this anonymous method as a parameter of `setState()`

  //Create Text
  createText(String text) => Text(text);

  //Refresh Icon
  refreshIcon() => Icon(Icons.refresh);
```

}

**Step 3**: Now, just take a break. You have to create a `StatefulWidget` which include `_isLoading` property.

```
class DarkXAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  var _isLoading = true;

  @override
  _DarkXAppHomePageState createState() => _DarkXAppHomePageState();
}

class _DarkXAppHomePageState extends State<DarkXAppHomePage> {
  //homepage Refresh Action
  refreshHomePage() => setState(() => widget._isLoading = false); // ★ => Just look at this. It have a obscure technique here. If you have right impelement which detail here (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), Flutter framework auto put the instance of your `DarkXAppHomePage` inside `_DarkXAppHomePageState` with the named `widget`. As you see, the `_DarkXAppHomePageState` force state of `State<DarkXAppHomePage>` and `DarkXAppHomePage` have `createState()` method which provided `_DarkXAppHomePageState`.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //Scaffold For Home Page
      home: Scaffold(
        //AppBar For Home Page
        appBar: AppBar(
          //Create Text
          title: Text('Welcome'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              //Refresh Icon
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () => refreshHomePage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: widget._isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('Finished Loading'),
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

**Step 4**: Connect your `DarkXAppHomePage` to main.

```
main() => runApp(DarkX());

class DarkX extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DarkXAppHomePage();
}
```

I wrote this code without IDE so if I have any typo error, please feel free to help me fix it.

Comment: Thankx for all the help.. :)

Comment: @SurjavaGhosh: Accept my answer if it's useful.

Comment: Yeah ... Thankx Mate you got me out of a serious bind there..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Callback function when pass function to another widget

```
Widget refreshButton(VoidCallBack onPress){
  Widget refreshicon = refreshIcon();
  Widget refreshbutton = new IconButton(icon: refreshicon, onPressed: onPress,);
  return refreshbutton;
}
```

Your code looks over-engineered, Maybe simplified things make it easy to understand. And always declare type to be a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this, maybe is me but founded difficult to follow your code the way you have it.

The setState must be inside of the statefullWidget, or be send as a parameter from there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(new DarkX());

class DarkX extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DarkXState createState() => _DarkXState();
}

class _DarkXState extends State<DarkX> {
  var _isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: createHomePageScaffold(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
  }

  //Scaffold For Home Page
  createHomePageScaffold() {
    var homeAppbar = homeAppBar();
    var homebody = homeBody();
    var scaffold = new Scaffold(
      appBar: homeAppbar,
      body: homebody,
    );
    return scaffold;
  }

  //AppBar For Home Page
  homeAppBar() {
    var text = createText('Welcome');
    var refreshbutton = refreshButton(refreshHomePage);
    var appBar = new AppBar(
      title: text,
      actions: <Widget>[refreshbutton],
    );
    return appBar;
  }

  //Body For Home Page
  homeBody() {
    var loadingState = _isLoading
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : createText('Finished Loading');
    return new Center(child: loadingState);
  }

  refreshButton(Function onPress) {
    var refreshicon = refreshIcon();
    var refreshbutton = new IconButton(
      icon: refreshicon,
      onPressed: () {
        onPress();
      },
    );
    return refreshbutton;
  }

  //homepage Refresh Action
  refreshHomePage() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  //Create Text
  createText(String text) {
    var newText = new Text(text);
    return newText;
  }

  //Refresh Icon
  refreshIcon() {
    var refreshicon = new Icon(Icons.refresh);
    return refreshicon;
  }
}
```

Comment: This Gave me the correct idea.. of what I was doing wrong.. thankx Mate.